# Android - Sony Xperia Z1 - Fatal spin-on-suspend, dumping threads

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask, android-service

I have an error during a background service (an Intent service). This is part of the logcat:

02-07 17:42:09.401: E/dalvikvm(27243): Fatal spin-on-suspend, dumping threads

02-07 17:42:09.421: E/dalvikvm(27243): threadid=15: stuck on threadid=17, giving up

02-07 17:42:09.421: A/libc(27243): Fatal signal 16 (SIGSTKFLT) at 0x00006a6b (code=-6), thread 28821 (IntentService[S)

Inside the service i call an asyncTask to do some background work (in another way, without using an asyncTask, the app throws an exception) such sending a heavy video splited into 1M parts.

This situation is so strange because only have this problem with the Sony Xperia Z1. I've tested in a Nexus7, GalaxyTab2 without problems.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Regards,
rmuhamed.

Comment: got the same issue with my project on Sony Xperia Z, running fine on other devices like Nexus...  did you solved it ?

Comment: erwin, how are you? I posted an "answer" that's works for me, have you seen it? I hope has been helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved by myself. I have no idea if it's the best solution but, now, is working fine.

Apparently the problem was that the OS was destroying the service because, based on priority category of IntentServices*, the low priority of it.

I have to add some custom logic to **onTaskRemoved** and **onDestroy** methods in my IntenteService class. On one hand, inside those methods i added a flag to control if the service was destroyed and invoke AsyncTask.stop() (to force asynctask finish). On the other hand, inside my asynctask, i have to verify this flag to prevent do logic if the service was stopped previously.

I think some code was hepful. Tell me that if you need it.

I hope this was helpful.